# Using Blazor components (Telerik / MudBlazor) in Razor ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor, umbraco

I have tried (unsuccessfully) using Telerik and / or MudBlazor components in Umbraco - ASP.NET Core 6 MVC razor view application (running razor components on razor views - hence Blazor components, because .NET Core ones are not able to run in razor components). Is using javascript components really the only way?

I configure services, everything works fine, but then the wrapper syntax (`<MudThemeProvider/>` for mudblazor) is not being recognized.

For Telerik, I get an error, where it says that some `Telerik.Documents.Spreadsheets` assembly is missing; I copied the .dll files from elsewhere and referenced it in the project and it still does not work.

Does anybody know if it's even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way can allow you use blazor components in Razor Page. Here's what I test:
Step1: Create your blazor component and put it under the folder ***Components***, here is the following content:

```
<h3>Count</h3>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    [Parameter]
    public int InitialValue { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount() => currentCount++;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        currentCount = InitialValue;
    }
}
```

Step2: Change the ***Program.cs*** file to add Blazor services ***builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();*** and map the required endpoints ***endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();***

Step3: Integrate the Blazor component into a razor page, such as ***Index.razor***, and add the script. Following code is which adding to the index.razor:

```
<component type="typeof(YourProjectName.Components.Counter)" param-InitialValue="0" render-mode="Server" />

@section Scripts {
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
}
```

After this, it should be working:
[image: Demo Pic]
If my answer is helpful to your porblem, please give me a mark, thank you for your support.
Great Day.

Comment: I marked as the answer, but I have a different problem; I wanted to use 3rd party components like Telerik or Mudblazor in razor components that are rendered in razor mvc projects. I already knew how to do what you showed here.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/3398?sort=new. Thank you for your mark.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely should be possible, there's nothing inherently different about using a third-party component library to using your own components.

The first step is to get a basic Blazor component working on your Umbraco site. I think you've done that already, but if not [This blog post](https://cornehoskam.com/posts/how-to-use-server-side-blazor-with-umbraco-9-live-notifications) describes how to do that.  There are a [few posts on the Umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.com/search?q=blazor&cat=forum) about that too.

Once you have that working, the steps in either the guides for [getting Telerik working in Blazor](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/getting-started/server-blazor) or [getting MudBlazor up and running](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#online-playground) should hopefully get their components working in your project.

If things aren't working after when working through one of those guides, I'd suggest putting a minimal reproducible example in a public repo and then asking a more specific question about the exact issue you're stuck on.

A couple of things worth checking once you have Telerik/Blazor set up:

- Make sure their CSS and JavaScript files are showing in the list of source files in the browser
- If you are using Blazor WebAssembly, check the the DLLs are actually getting to the browser.  You may need to change the publishing settings on those files in Visual Studio.